# Open shell and execute python code with fabric

Tags: python, django, fabric

For my Django project I had a script that worked with `subprocess` to open the `manage.py shell` and execute python code like that

```
proc = subprocess.Popen( [
    manage, "shell",
], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate(
    "from django.contrib.auth.models import User; ..."
     )
)
```

Now I'd like to do this with `fabric`. How can I run `manage.py shell` and put some code in there using `fabric`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piping code to the manage shell looks very hacky.

I recommend you write a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/) or a [standalone script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) instead. Using fabric to run a script on a remote machine should be straight forward.